# Store a table as a field of collection mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

is it possible to store a table in a collection?

I want to do something like this:

`db.mycollection.insert({"name": 'test1', "subcollection": """Need Table Here like mycollection so I can insert in it"""})`

Answer (score 0):

If you can present your table like object - just do it. Or use some CSV-representation of your table (and save like string property).

Use `mongodb` NPM to work with MongoDB: "https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb". Also you can use `mongoose` NPM (ORM for MongoDB): "https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose".